# Is there any chance of conflict if I make 100 simultaneous http request asynchronously to same destination from same source?

Tags: windows, jsp, http, networking, web

(1) If I make a hundred http request asynchronously from a client application to a single destination(i.e- same ip/port), is there any chance of conflict in the client side?

What I understand is whenever an application makes a http request the OS assigns a random port as source, and the server response is sent to that source port only. As the requests are asynchronous and too many, can there be cases where OS assigns a same source port to another of this 100 request, and when the server responses actually for the first request the second request also receives that response?

(2) Even if conflict is not probable for 100 request, is there any upper limit to this(because ports are limited, and number of simultaneous requests made are nearly same or more)?

(3) And is the scenario same for all applications(whether using a Winforms client or a curl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create maximum of 65535 (2^16 - 1) ports in a system - including server and client ports.

Ans 1: The ports won't overlap/conflict when you make 100 or above simultaneous requests. But make sure at the server side, whether you can do such huge requests from a particular system/network.

Ans 2: Upper limit is 65535.

And 3: Yes, this limit is for all the ports used by the application running in the system.

Comment: Does that mean when a request is sent, that source port is not available to be assigned to another http request as source port by OS? How long does the OS keep it that way- until it gets response from the server? Or times out? And then immediately opens the port to be available for other new requests?

Comment: Yes, actually the port is like a handle and the OS will keep it open for that process/thread till it is closed by the application or the application is terminated. Once the port is closed, it will be available for others. But it will be rarely assigned to other requester immediately.